# What object class in adonis R is required as input?

Tags: r

This question might sound obvious - but does adonis in R require to have a distance matrix as input data or does it transform it within the function? I have two metric variables (isotope data, all negative but I could use its absolute values instead)? I cannot see this within the adonis code if I view it.

This are my 2 VAR

```
structure(list(`CSIA_fish_EFA_eyes[1:5, 8]` = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("epilithon", "inverts", "salmonid.eyes"
), class = "factor"), ALA.d13C = c(48, 43, 49, 47, 52), LIN.d13C = c(38, 
36, 42, 40, 44)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(84L, 88L, 
92L, 96L, 104L))
```

I do not have a community matrix but I want to check if two groups differ in both of these parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a formula, data.frame, and provides some other options. You will have to pick your preferred method.

I just changed some of the names in your data.frame. From a substantive perspective, if you are interested in using the absolute value, you can consider Manhattan distance.

```
df <- structure(list(eyes = structure(c(3L, 
                                              3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("epilithon", "inverts", "salmonid.eyes"
                                              ), class = "factor"), Ad13C = c(48, 43, 49, 47, 52), Ld13C = c(38, 
                                              36, 42, 40, 44)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(84L, 88L,                                                                                                                                                                                 92L, 96L, 104L))

m1 <- vegan::adonis(data = df, Ad13C ~ Ld13C, method = "bray" ) # see ?vegan::vegdist

m1


# Call:
#   vegan::adonis(formula = Ad13C ~ Ld13C, data = df) 
# 
# Permutation: free
# Number of permutations: 119
# 
# Terms added sequentially (first to last)
# 
# Df SumsOfSqs   MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)  
# Ld13C      1 0.0039911 0.0039911   15.15 0.83472   0.05 *
#   Residuals  3 0.0007903 0.0002634         0.16528         
# Total      4 0.0047814                   1.00000         
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
m2 <- vegan::adonis(data = df, Ad13C ~ Ld13C, method = "manhattan" )
m2
# Call:
#   vegan::adonis(formula = Ad13C ~ Ld13C, data = df, method = "manhattan") 
# 
# Permutation: free
# Number of permutations: 119
# 
# Terms added sequentially (first to last)
# 
# Df SumsOfSqs MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)  
# Ld13C      1      36.1  36.100  16.164 0.84346   0.05 *
#   Residuals  3       6.7   2.233         0.15654         
# Total      4      42.8                 1.00000         
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Or, with a matrix as a response

```
df$oth <- rnorm(length(df$Ad13C), 10*df$Ld13C, 10) 

m3 <- vegan::adonis(data = df, df[,c("Ad13C","oth")] ~ Ld13C, method = "bray" ) # see ?vegan::vegdist

m3
```

Comment: Ah I see, so default is bray-curtis dissimilarity. So my input data does not need to be a distance matrix per se. I could also use another formular e.g.: df [,2:3] ~ factor if I want to test, if both parameters differs abetween groups? like in a manova?

Comment: yes that formula should work as well, from the documentation: "The functions partition sums of squares of a multivariate data set, and they are directly analogous to MANOVA (multivariate analysis of variance). McArdle and Anderson (2001) and Anderson (2001) refer to the method as “permutational manova” (formerly “nonparametric manova”)." Its easy enough to extend the example, but remember to accept the answer if it satisfies your question.